# Function nested in array with reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int main() {
    int broccoli,peppers[3]={4,3,2,1} , *zucchini;
    zucchini = &peppers[Saute(peppers,1)];
    cout<<zucchini<<endl;
}
```

I know peppers[2] = 2 but just wonder why after Saute function the value of  peppers[2] = 3 ? because I think that i only reference the peppers to zucchini and I never declare smtg like this = Saute(&peppers,1)

```
int Saute(int onions[], int celery) {
    celery *= 2;
    onions[celery]++;
    return celery;
}
```

Comment: `why after Saute function the value of peppers[2] = 3 ?` because: `onions[celery]++;`.

Comment: `peppers[3]={4,3,2,1}` You mean `peppers[4]={4,3,2,1}` ?

Comment: `peppers` is an array of 3 `int`s but you want to cram 4 values in it. `zucchini` is a pointer, are you sure you want to print it as such, or maybe you want to print `*zucchini`? When passed as an argument to a function an array decays into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @DimChtz but isnt there is a peppers[0] for first element?

Comment: @Perfectisshit Yes, but the size of your array is 4 not 3.

Comment: @DimChtz oh i know my mistake now.  thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, when you pass an array to a function, the array is not copied but passed "as reference" (actually parameter `peppers` of type `int[3]` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. to an `int*`, and the type of argument `int onions[]` is equivalent to `int *`, too). Hence, when you pass `peppers` as parameter to function argument `onions`, and in the function increase a value of the array through `onions[celery]++`, then you actually increase a value of array `pepper`.
That's why...

BTW: `peppers[3]={4,3,2,1}` should be `peppers[4]={4,3,2,1}`, and you should have got a compiler warning here.

Comment: i just checked it on web,  dint know that array work that way.  Thx for it!